# Multiple TransactionManagers in Spring. Select a default

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aop

Have two transactionManagers registered as below-

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager1" />
        <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager2" />
```

Is it possible to make one of these the default.
I mean if transactionManager1 is to be used then only use @transactional above methods.
If transactionManager2 is to be used then use qualifier as 
@transactional(transactionManager2) above methods.

Comment: Having 2 `<tx:annotation-driven />` elements is useless. Only the last one remains so currently `transactionManager2` is the default.

Comment: actually <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager1" />
is in different configuration file and <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager2" />in other.                Have to make transactionManager1 as default.                                      So if I use only <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager1" /> making it default and for transactionManager2 use qualifiers will it work?..thnks

Comment: Yes. As stated only 1 `<tx:annotation-driven />` will be taken into account, the last one loaded wins and is the default.

Comment: Thanks a lot M. Deinum..